# API Response to deserialize in Class

Tags: c#, json

I given my API Response please help for how to Set Data in Class using like Deserialize

```
{
"result": [
{
"encabezado": {
"resultado": "true",
"imensaje": "",
"mensaje": "",
"tiempo": "28"
},
"respuesta": {
"datos": {
"crear": "true"
}
}
}
]
}
```

Can you help for how to set in class

I'm using it like:

```
var json = "{'result': " +
            "[{'encabezado': " +
            "{'resultado': 'true','imensaje': '','mensaje': '','tiempo': '28'}," +
            "'respuesta': " +
            "{'datos': {'crear': 'true'}}}]}";

result info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

```
public class encabezado
    {
        public string resultado { get; set; }
        public string imensaje { get; set; }
        public string mensaje { get; set; }
        public string tiempo { get; set; }
    }
    public class datos
    {
        public string crear { get; set; }
    }

    public class result
    {
        public encabezado encabezado { get; set; }
        public datos respuesta { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: make sure that JSON is in proper format

Comment: If that is in proper format then use deserialize

Comment: can you tell me which place in my mistake    var json = "{'result': [{'encabezado': {'resultado': 'true','imensaje': '','mensaje': '','tiempo': '28'},'respuesta': {'datos': {'crear': 'true'}}}]}";

            encabezado info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<encabezado>(json);

Comment: jay and prashant thans for reply please check i updated my question and codes as i used so please reply as some solve problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using Json.NET, use the following class structure:

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Result[] result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Encabezado encabezado { get; set; }
        public Respuesta respuesta { get; set; }
    }

    public class Encabezado
    {
        public string resultado { get; set; }
        public string imensaje { get; set; }
        public string mensaje { get; set; }
        public string tiempo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Respuesta
    {
        public Datos datos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datos
    {
        public string crear { get; set; }
    }
```

And to deserialize:

```
    var json = "{'result': [{'encabezado': {'resultado': 'true','imensaje': '','mensaje': '','tiempo': '28'},'respuesta': {'datos': {'crear': 'true'}}}]}";
    RootObject info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

**TIP:** In Visual Studio, you can copy your JSON and go to `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes` and it will automatically generate the classes for you.